# Web Client Software Factory Unit Testing Big Fail

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, wcsf

it is me again...too much question, I know, but in this I'm kind of a newbie...

Well, I have a problem creating test for a project that is built using Microsoft's Web Client Software Factory: I get a error that says:

> Unable to set TestContext property for the class MyClassName. Error:  System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.TestTypes.Unit.UnitTestAdapterContext' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestContext'..

and the test never runs, any ideas?

Again, thanks in advance =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, one of those seely details: I just had to update the reference of these libraries:

- Microsoft.VisalStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
- Microsoft.VisalStudio.QualityTools.WebTestFramework

from version 8.0 to 9.0. Really seely, but that worked.

Thanks for everything.

Answer (score 0):

What is the type of the TestContext property of your MyClassName class? According to the error message, it's the wrong type. Compare it with the tests that work.

Comment: The thing is, I don't a test that works... :/ and, in MyClassName I don't have a TestContext property.

Thanks, I think this is a first good tip to continue the search =)

Comment: Doesn't the factory come with unit tests already? Look at one of those. Also, does your class have a base class? Maybe the property is in the base class.

Comment: Well, it turns out I do not need that "TestContext" (or at least), it seems that: I just deleted that property and I was able to run the tests...well, I will follow that path and hope not to find more troubles...thanks John =)

Comment: Thanks Hugo, deleting the "TestContext" property worked for me too :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is the kind of non-specific answer I hate, but here goes anyway:

Use a different unit test framework!

I've spent at least 3 times more time fixing tests that fail because of MSTest's "features" than fixing code that has bugs.

Feel free to downvote this because it doesn't help Hugo.  My true aim is to help warn others away from the MSTest beast.